# Setting target framerate changes animation speed in editor, while Time.deltaTime stays the same

Tags: unity, frame-rate, timestep

I have few animations that work similar to this:

```
IEnumerator MoveObjTo(GameObject obj1, GameObject ob2, float time)
{
    var start = obj1.transform.position.x;
    var end = obj2.transform.position.x;

    float passedPath = 0f;
    var s = end - start;
    float speed = (end - start) / time;
    while (passedPath < s)
    {
        var ds = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        var newPos = obj.transform.position;
        newPos.x += ds;
        obj.transform.position = newPos;
        passedPath += ds;
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

It worked fine until I added this line to my code:

```
Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
```

After this, inside the Unity editor animation started to work 10 times faster (it's still OK on device). And I noticed that if I set `targetFrameRate` to the same FPS value as shown in the editor's Stats (400 FPS), to the animation speed is fixed.

If I print `Time.deltaTime` and `ds` inside this method, I'll get about the same values and it looks like `Time.timeDelta is always 0.017`, but with different `targetFrameRate` values that same 0.017 corresponds to different real time intervals.

I'll fix it by `ifdef`ing the `targetFrameRate` setup, I'm just curious how this works.

Comment: Not sure if this is what's causing your issue but the Unity Editor only redraws the scene when it needs to. If you're not moving the viewport and nothing is updating, it won't re-render the editor view. As such, `Time.deltaTime` can vary wildly and may represent several seconds per frame. Are the fast animations purely in the editor view? Or also when in Play mode?

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: @Basic idk, I logged timeDelta in while cycle(so, every frame, I guess) and it was always about ~0.017

Comment: @Kevin it's 2021.3.1f1

Comment: Btw, DOTween animations working perfectly well.

Comment: @daedal99 I believe the latest version of 2021 is 2021.3.9f1; you should consider updating to the latest version to see if it's an Editor bug

Comment: @Kevin thanks, it works as it should after update; rly seems to be editor bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things you can check:

1. Make sure you aren't changing `Time.timeScale` anywhere.
2. Make sure you aren't setting `Time.captureDeltaTime` or `Time.captureFramerate` anywhere.
3. See if you can update the Unity Editor to a newer version, in case it's a bug in the Editor.